# PID With Prediction

Tags: c#, algorithm, prediction

I have a stream of data that I get at around 10 snapshots per second. I wrote a C# controller that takes this data and adjusts some data-gathering parameters based on the distance away from the expected result. Currently, I just do a linear scale operation on my data so that the farther away I am from the expected result the more it corrects. The problem is that the incoming data stream is delayed by somewhere between 0.5 and 2 seconds (I can calculate that at runtime). Because of this delay, it is correcting for results from a while ago and is constantly overcorrecting and even correcting in the wrong direction sometimes.
I am looking for an algorithm to do the following:

- Implement a correction algorithm (I'd prefer PID) that will attempt to hone-in on the optimal value
- Predict a certain amount of time (or number of datasets) in advance based on the history of corrections and results

What options do I have in terms of algorithms that can accomplish this? 
C# code samples would be appreciated; I am not great at converting complex pseudo-code in to a working implementation.

Comment: You're much more likely to receive a reply to this if you post on [Signal Processing Stack Exchange](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/). I doubt most users here even know what a PID controller is without having to look it up.

Comment: I have asked programming-related algorithm questions on SE forums for algorithms in the past; They usually respond with some complex 20-page paper on algorithms or a 100-line block of pseudo-code ;) I decided I didn't want to risk it this time, but I might have to if this doesn't turn up anything...

Comment: It's a math-heavy subject, the sure-fire way to a solution is to start tackling the subject yourself (if you have math anxiety this is a very unfortunate situation to find yourself into, but it's fixable). The other option would be to start looking for Matlab or Python (with NumPy and SciPy) code samples for your problem, and convert them to C#, you might actually find something that suits you.

Comment: PID is the standard solution for this, the algorithm is exceeding simple.  The hard requirement is that you have to *tune* it.  Set I and D to zero, tweak P so the system follows but doesn't get close to being unstable.  You'll have a constant error, increase I to get rid of it.  Which has a habit of overshooting, having too much of a memory of what happened before.  Allow it to overshoot but not excessively.  Then increase D to get rid of the eagerness, damping the overshoots.  A step input is the best way to tune.

Comment: I understand what PID is and how it works. What I am looking for is a way to incorporate prediction in to the algorithm so that I can correct for the delay.

Comment: Have you looked at learning AI like neural networks?

Comment: @pallandt, I have taken your advice and asked a question about this on the Signal Processing SE forum. I will probably close this question within a day.